# Summing Numbers in a For Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum

I cannot figure out how to sum all of my loop instances to get the grand total at the end.  I'm unsure of what I am doing wrong.  My total always comes to $10504.76 which is very far off.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double salary = 0.01, totalSalary = 0;

    System.out.printf("Your current salary is: $%.2f\n", salary);

    for (double i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        salary *= 2;
        totalSalary = salary + i;
        System.out.printf("Your current salary is: $%.2f\n ", salary);
    }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Total Salary over 20 days is: $%.2f", totalSalary);
}
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: To find out what you do wrong, use both unit tests and a debugger. Moreover, when you work with money, I recommend using `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: how far is it "off"? ...it looks pretty exact as `0,01 $ * 2^20` ...! (count me in that job :)

Comment: Hi, my total should be $20,971.51, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `i` instead of adding the `salary` itself:

```
for (double i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    salary *= 2;
    totalSalary += salary; // Here!
    System.out.printf("Your current salary is: $%.2f\n ", salary);
}
```

Comment: @ZacharyMull This is where simply putting a print statement in the loop and printing out the various values might have helped.  When it comes to debugging, `System.out.println` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful. I'll have to keep that in mind.